# No puedo descifrar el contenido de un array en php con mysql

Tags: php, mysql, array

Mi base de datos almacena los datos en una sola columna de esta manera :

```
08:00:00 - 08:40:00#matematicas (MAT33)#H12 (Hilandera)#jesus cuicas/
08:40:00 - 09:20:00#matematicas (MAT33)#H12 (Hilandera)#luis lopez/
09:20:00 - 10:40:00#matematicas (MAT33)#G43 (Giraluna)#fdsfs fdsfds/
10:40:00 - 12:00:00#matematicas (MAT33)#G43 (Giraluna)#fdsfs fdsfds/
```

Separa un día con `/` y los elementos dentro con `#`, necesito tener cada campo por separado para poder compararlo a otras tablas pero esta muy complicado de obtener.

Las columnas son los días de la semana:

```
$horarios['Lunes']==NULL ? $lunes='' : $lunes=$horarios['Lunes'];
```

Luego separo de esta manera:

```
$lunes=='' ? $lunes='' : $lunesx=explode('/',$lunes);
```

Las horas las obtengo de la siguiente forma:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($lunesx)-1;$i++){
  $separar_lunesx=explode('#',$lunesx[$i]);
  $sepa_lunesx[]=explode('-',$separar_lunesx[0]);
}
```

Pero, cuando intento sacar los datos, `$separar_lunesx` sólo me trae los últimos campos

Comment: He editado la pregunta para intentar clarificarla, pero no logro entenderla. ¿Podrías detallar lo que esperas obtener?

Comment: El problema es que tu base de datos no debería almacenar tantos datos juntos en una sola fila/columna. ¿Hay algo que justifique eso? Ese diseño será inviable tarde o temprano y tendrás que normalizarlo. Sea como sea, si quieres resolverlo a la fuerza, por código, es posible, pero quizá tengas que pasarte la vida parcheando el código mientras no resuelvas el problema de raíz. Si quieres continuar por este camino, explica con claridad el problema para que podamos ayudarte a resolverlo.

Comment: la intencion es crear un horario en base a esos datos guardados tengo que desglosarlos y hacer que los imprima en un pdf , pero quien programo eso lo hizo de esa manera quien sabe por que y no puedo cambiarlo a estas alturas por falta de tiempo y tendria que alterar toda la documentacion para justificarlo .

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto es lo que buscás:

input (string):

```
$datos = "08:00:00 - 08:40:00#matematicas (MAT33)#H12 (Hilandera)#jesus cuicas/08:40:00 - 09:20:00#matematicas (MAT33)#H12 (Hilandera)#luis lopez/09:20:00 - 10:40:00#matematicas (MAT33)#G43 (Giraluna)#fdsfs fdsfds/10:40:00 - 12:00:00#matematicas (MAT33)#G43 (Giraluna)#fdsfs fdsfds";
```

Código:

```
$resultado = array();

$dias = explode('/', $datos);

foreach($dias as $dia) {
    $resultado[] = explode("#", $dia);
}
```

Salida (var_dump($resultado)):

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '08:00:00 - 08:40:00' (length=19)
      1 => string 'matematicas (MAT33)' (length=19)
      2 => string 'H12 (Hilandera)' (length=15)
      3 => string 'jesus cuicas' (length=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '08:40:00 - 09:20:00' (length=19)
      1 => string 'matematicas (MAT33)' (length=19)
      2 => string 'H12 (Hilandera)' (length=15)
      3 => string 'luis lopez' (length=10)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '09:20:00 - 10:40:00' (length=19)
      1 => string 'matematicas (MAT33)' (length=19)
      2 => string 'G43 (Giraluna)' (length=14)
      3 => string 'fdsfs fdsfds' (length=12)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '10:40:00 - 12:00:00' (length=19)
      1 => string 'matematicas (MAT33)' (length=19)
      2 => string 'G43 (Giraluna)' (length=14)
      3 => string 'fdsfs fdsfds' (length=12)
```